# How do I find (or exclude) all directories and sub-directories matching a certain pattern (in Linux)?

Tags: linux, directory, find, recursive

I'm trying to use the Linux find command to find all directories and sub-directories that do not have .svn (Subversion hidden folders) in their path. I can only get it to exclude the actual .svn directories themselves, but not any of the sub-directories.

Here is what I'm doing right now:

```
find . -type d \! -iname '*.svn*'
```

I've also tried:

```
find . -type d \! iname '.svn' \! iname '.svn/*'
```

Just an FYI, I'm trying to use the find pattern so I can apply some subversion properties to all directories in my repository excluding the subversion hidden folders and their sub-directories (by applying the exec command to the directories returned from the find command)..

TIA

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
find . -type d -not \( -name .svn -prune \)
```

Comment: I'll go with this one, though they all seemed to work.

Comment: I've used -prune on find before, but I hadn't seen that \\( ... \\) trick. Thanks.

Comment: Can you tell how this would work in a node.js / express app where I want to exclude node-modules from counting the lines? I tried

`find . -name '*.js' -not \( -name 'node_modules'  -prune \) | xargs wc -l` 

without success ...

Comment: In response to @shredding regarding Node.js / Express apps and excluding node_modules directories from find's results, this works for me: find . -name '*.test.js' -not \(-wholename '*node_modules*' \) ... given that the tests i want to run are suffixed with ".test.js"

Comment: Would this work without the `-type d`? I like to search for all file but exclude the ".git" dir recursively

Answer (score 5):

What about simply

```
find . -type d |  grep -v '.svn'
```

Comment: Loses your ability to use any of the find actions.

Comment: Yes, but what about a nice little sh loop instead? :) 

for FILE in `find . -type d |  grep -v '.svn'`; do echo whatever; done

Comment: That way you also exclude files with the pattern, not only folders and sub-folders of the offending folder.

Answer (score 5):

What about the `-path` option to find?

```
find . -type d ! -path '*.svn*'
```

Comment: Missed off a closing quote. There's an outside chance that the wildcards might be too greedy.

Answer (score 3):

You could use:

```
find . -type d -not -wholename '*.svn*'
```

Comment: it stripped the * from the front of the answer... 
should be find . -type d -not -wholename '*/.svn/*'
(that's wholename squote asterisk slash dot svn slash asterisk squote)

Answer (score 2):

find . -path './tmp' -prune -o .......