# How can I specify a shell pattern that excludes certain files?

Tags: shell, pattern-matching

For instance, I want to remove all the files in a directory except for the `.tar` file from whence they came. I could do something like:

```
find . -maxdepth 0 | grep -v '.tar$' | xargs rm -f
```

but is there a way to do is just using rm and **shell pattern matching**? Feel free to specify it using `bash` or other commonly available shells, or with extended options, if it can't be done with vanilla `sh`.

I found a similar question about [avoiding directories and subdirectories with find](https://serverfault.com/questions/33308/how-do-i-find-or-exclude-all-directories-and-sub-directories-matching-a-certain), but not with shell patterns.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do it with extended globbing.

```
shopt -s extglob
```

then

```
rm !(file.tar)
```

This works in bash 3.2.39 at a minimum

Comment: This is the only answer so far that addresses the question with an answer. Thanks Cian...

Comment: Is that recursive? When I run a similar command with `ls` it appears to be. If so, um, be very careful.

Comment: @telemachus doesn't appear to be when I try it. It may depend on whether you have globstar turned on though.

Comment: Telemachus: I don't think its recursive, it would just include directories as well.  ls expands directories u.nless you use the -d switch

Comment: @Kyle: facepalm. I'm an idiot and clearly am not thinking very quickly. Thanks, that was it.

Comment: Hi @Cian, was hoping to maximize votes for your answer. My unproven theory is that people are more likely to vote for the right answer when it isn't yet the accepted answer. But I see that after I accepted your answer, you immediately got another vote :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this perhaps

```
find . -maxdepth 0 \! -name '*.tar' -exec echo rm -f {} \;
```

Remove the echo preceding the rm if it looks right.

> Yes, but is there a shell pattern?

I don't think so.  At least not in the versions of bash I am familiar with.  From the other answers it appears that newer versions may be more functional.

Comment: Wildcard on the end of tar doesn't match the original regex anchor. I presume the OP was using egrep.

Comment: You can do it with extglobbing in bash.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think what you want to achieve is possible.

You could however simplify the command you have:

```
find . -maxdepth 0 -not -name '*.tar' -exec rm -f {} +
```

Comment: Possible, but if you get it slightly wrong, look out. I wouldn't really recommend it, though I know you're just trying to answer the OP's request.

Answer (score 0):

Edit:

Read the question to fast...  But in to continue with my post anyways... :-)  If you want to delete all *files* but tar files recursively with zsh:

```
rm -rf **/^*.tar(.)
```

Non-Recursive:

```
rm -rf ^*.tar(.)
```

The new bash 4.0 and and zsh support recursive globbing.  To enable it in bash use:

```
shopt -s globstar
```

It works like:

```
 rm -rf **/*.tar.gz
```

Comment: Wow. That gives me all kinds of fear :D

Comment: Um, yes, that doesn't seem like a good idea _at all_.

Comment: Why not, just use it with echo first to make sure You don't delete the wrong stuff...

Comment: Use it with `echo` first is always good advice, but I suppose I worry a lot about that _one_ time when you're going too quickly and forget `echo`. `**/` makes me nervous for destructive commands.